# MSSQL - show columns in specific table and database

Tags: sql-server

Not quite getting how to enumerate the columns within a specific database and table.

I can list all the databases using:

```
SELECT name from master..sysdatabases
go
```

I can show all the tables for a specific database

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ValidUsers.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

I'm then trying to list all the columns for a specific table, which brings up nothing. Im guessing I need to somehow specify the database, but I can't work out how to do it.

```
select COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'Admins'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the database as the active database-context using `use` before executing the SELECT-Statement.

So it would:

```
USE mydatabase;
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'Admins';
```

An alternative would be to include the database as a prefix to the information_schema like this:

```
SELECT column_name FROM [mydatabase].information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'Admins';
```

Comment: `information_schema.columns` is a reference to `database.table` so the query is self-sufficient

Comment: I'm not a hundred percent sure what you mean by that but I did edit my answer having another look at it. Was the possibility to prefix the information_schema with the database what you wanted to point out?

Comment: Sorry for being obscure: I meant to point at `USE` being useless if you already reference the database information_schema in the `SELECT` query. But as I see your answer was accepted, so it had probably done some magic trick :)

Comment: The problem is that the [information_schema.columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx) "Returns one row for each column that can be accessed by the current user in the **current database**." (Emphasis added). As such you won't get any results if you don't somehow set a DB context. For this you'd (from my knowledge) have to either `USE` or prefix the database name. At least if it's not part of the default context for the user.

Comment: Well, I don't know how I read mysql in the question in the first place, sorry for messing things up.

Comment: It made me refine the answer and I actually learned a few bits while doing so myself so it's all OK! After all having a single query can be way nicer depending on what she/he actually is doing. :) Have a nice ... decade. :D